# Array loading first object twice in before moving onto the second object in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have a simple app that fetches Post objects from my Firebase database and appends them to my array of posts. I am able to get everything functioning properly and I'm able to fetch / display everything like normal but when the view loads for the first time and I tap my button, calling the **nextItem()** function, I have to click next twice before loading the second item.

It will display the first item when the view loads as well as when I tap the button for the first time. Anything after that point loads perfectly in order.

All relevant code is below:

```
var posts = [Post]()
var arrayIndex: Int = 0
var arrayInt: Int = 1
```

inside my viewDidLoad I call this function that fetches all the data and then in the completion block, I call the **getUsersDetailsFromArray()**

```
fetchPosts {
    self.getUsersDetailsFromArray()
}
```

When I hit the button that fetches the next object, I call this function:

```
func nextItem() {

self.likeImageView.alpha = 0

if arrayIndex >= self.posts.count - 1 {
    arrayIndex = 0
    arrayInt = 1
} else if arrayIndex <= self.posts.count - 1 {
    arrayIndex += 1
    arrayInt += 1
}

    getUsersDetailsFromArray()
}
```

Here is the getUserDetialsFromArray function:

```
func getUsersDetailsFromArray() {
self.displayName.text = self.posts[self.arrayIndex].author
self.postImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: self.posts[self.arrayIndex].postImageUrl!)
self.profileImage.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: self.posts[self.arrayIndex].avatar_image_url!)
}
```

Comment: Step through the code and see that self.posts contains what you think it should and that it goes into the right part of the if/else in nextItem().  There's a lot that could go wrong, but you can't tell from this code -- you need to debug it and give us more information about the value of the variables at each point.